# Scaling ViewGroup, keeping it aligned at the bottom

Tags: android, animation

I want to scale a ViewGroup, but keeping it aligned at the bottom, is this at all possible?

If I scale the view with the ViewPropertyAnimator, the view is scaled in a way that a lot of "white space" is generated below the ViewGroup.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/MessagesView_ListFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/paddingLeft"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/paddingRight"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

    <com.customwidget.ScrollBar
        android:id="@+id/InboxView_ScrollBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Scaling it like this:

```
    findViewById(R.id.content).animate().scaleX(0.75f).scaleY(0.75f).setDuration(750).start();
```

Comment: The `View` is scaled relatively to its center. You can add a `translate` animation (seems that 0.25f would be correct regarding your code) so that the view translate in the same time it is scaled, so that its bottom stays aligned

Comment: Never used TranslateAnimation before. Could you perhaps show me how you would accomplish this? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe extending your code like this should suffice :

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.content);
v.animate()
.scaleX(0.75f)
.scaleY(0.75f) 
.translateY(v.getHeight() / 4) // Translates by 1/4 of the view's height to compensate the scale
.setDuration(750)
.start();
```

Some other workaround would be to set the pivot point of your View like this :

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.content);
v.setPivotY(v.getHeight()); // Can be set in an xml file using android:transformPivotY
// Use your original code here.
```

Comment: You can also set pivotY inside xml, if you already know your view's height: `android:transformPivotY="200dp"`